# send whats popping up in the console?

Tags: python, linux, discord.py

I have a run command with my discord bot, it basically runs a bash command from the terminal. It works perfectly fine, but I want the discord bot to send what the command is saying in the console. for example if you type .run pwd, it should send a message saying the current directory.
This is my code so far

```
@commands.check(owner)
async def run(ctx, *, arg):
  response = os.system(arg)
  ctx.author.send(response)
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
@commands.is_owner()
@client.command()
async def run(ctx, *, arg):
    response = os.popen(arg).read()
    try:
        await ctx.author.send(response)
    except:
        await ctx.author.send(f'/bin/sh: 1: {arg}: not found')
```